# Do any other IDEs have an quivlent to xcode's playgrounds?

Tags: xcode, ide

I recently finished a class taught in xcode. One thing I absolutely loved about the editor was the playground feature.

Playgrounds are (as I understand it) basically projects where each block of code is compiled on the fly, and outputs are printed next to the black of code. I could prototype classes and functions incredibly quickly.

I haven't used many IDEs, so for all I know, this might be a ubiquitous feature. But I've done some googleing, and I haven't found anything about this feature in other programs.

Comment: It appears that the playground is specific to the Swift programming language.  There are aids to rapid prototyping in other IDE's, but they work differently and require full programs rather than snippets.  For example, when debugging a class, there is a Run As Application option but this requires having a public static void main(String[]) method.

Comment: That's too bad. Is it due to a lack of demand, or some feature spesific to the Swift programming language?

Comment: Since Swift and Xcode come from the same source, that enables some things that wouldn't be practical with other IDE's. The other IDE's do such things as checking for syntax errors and other problems while writing the code.  I terms of medium to large programs, I'm not sure how much of a difference it makes in speed of programming.